# Regex in Python to find Rows in Table

Tags: python, regex, webdriver

i`m using python to automate some test, and at one point i find a table with rows, but this rows are of two different clases:

You have class name "gris-claro-tr" and "gris-oscuro-tr".

I need to iterate the whole table, finding the text of every row. Until now, i have:

```
        for row in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gris-claro-tr"):    
            cell = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[1]
            print (cell.text)
```

But of course, only works for the rows with that class. I have to do the same thing for "gris-oscuro-tr". However, if i could find a regex that could find both row`s class, i would get the text of every row in that table, no matter if it is "gris-claro-td" or "gris-oscuro-td".

The question is: how can i make that regex?

Is it something like "gris-"+"*" ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: try `gris-.*?-td`

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it with a *CSS selector*:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".gris-claro-tr,.gris-oscuro-tr")
```

`,` here means "or", dot defines a class name selector.

---

Or, you can apply the partial matches as well, a little bit less explicit though:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class^=gris][class$=tr]")
```

where `^=` means "starts with", `$=` means "ends with".

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. Now i have another problem: you have on each line a button with the text "canjear", the point is that i need to click the button that belongs to the row that has the text i need. How can i get the index of the row in this case?

Comment: @GHM sure, please see if you can create a separate SO question if you need further help. Don't forget to provide an HTML code of the table.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on XPATH you can use

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='gris-claro-tr'] or [@class='gris-oscuro-td'] ")
```

`*` can be replced by your tag name